# I cannot duplicate the a 2d matrix of strings. Facing problem in allocating and deallocating the memory

Tags: arrays, c, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings, string-literals

I am writing a C function which will return the string array.

This function will create an `char** matrix` array by dynamically allocating memory by using `malloc` inside itself. Then It will put `sin` `cos` `tan` in positions `matrix[0]` `matrix[1]` `matrix[2]` respectively.

Then this matrix will be duplicated inside another `char** matrix02` variable.

Then the `matrix` will be deleted by deallocating memory using `free()` and nullifying every element in `matrix`.

And then the `matrix02` will be returned.

But when I try to reach an element (Suppose `matrix[0]`), The output I get is...

**`(null)`**

I have researched about it. I found that I am only assigning pointer not duplicating the matrix, and when I delete the matrix the pointer is also nullified.

How to perform this action?
So that function should create matrix by allocating memory, duplicate the matrix, and then delete the matrix so that there is no memory issue.

I wanted to learn about it.

Here's my code.

```
//--------------- matrix.h ------------//

char** makeMatrix(){
    char** matrix = (char**)malloc(200);     
    
    matrix[0] = "sin";
    matrix[1] = "cos";
    matrix[2] = "tan";

    char** matrix02 = matrix;         //Duplicating matrix
    
    free(matrix);       //Deallocating memory

    int i = 0;
    while(matrix[i] != NULL){
        matrix[i] = NULL;           //Nulling all elements
        i++;
    }

    return matrix02;
}
```

```
//------------------- main.c -------------------//
#include <stdio.h>
#include "matrix.h"

int main(){
    char** myMatrix = makeMatrix();


    printf("%s\n", myMatrix[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The journey to understanding C can be perilous.  You're not the first to make these kinds of mistakes and you won't be the last.

Answer (score 1):

For starters this memory allocation with the magic number 200

```
char** matrix = (char**)malloc(200);
```

is confusing.

You should explicitly specify how many elements of the pointer type `char *` the allocated array must have.

After this declaration

```
char** matrix02 = matrix;         //Duplicating matrix
```

the both pointers `matrix` and `matrix02` point to the same dynamically allocated memory.

So after freeing the memory

```
free(matrix);
```

the both pointers will have invalid values.

Remove this statement.

You need to free the allocated array in main.

Also this while loop

```
int i = 0;
while(matrix[i] != NULL){
    matrix[i] = NULL;           //Nulling all elements
    i++;
}
```

have undefined behavior because only three elements of the dynamically allocated array were initialized. All other elements have indeterminate values and are not necessary equal to NULL.

Pay attention to that you should not place function definitions in a header if the corresponding functions are not inline or do not have internal linkage.